# How to convert March 10, 2017 to (dd,mm,yyyy) format?

Tags: javascript

My output consists below format
   February 9, 2017

How to Convert the above format to (dd,mm,yyyy) format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a lot of extremely quirky date formats out there, but that's even more unusual than most. Is that a custom thing?

Comment: this question is quite vague.  is your "output" a formatted `Date` object, or a `string`? are you trying to display the output differently, or trying to store the value differently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Date/Timestamp in a particular format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40372411/get-date-timestamp-in-a-particular-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with below solution:

```js
function dateFormat(stringDate){
  var date = new Date(stringDate);
  var day = (date.getDate()>9) ? date.getDate() : "0" + date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  month = (month>9) ? month : "0" + month;
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  // format your date as you expect
  var dateFormat = "("+year+","+month+","+day+")";
  return dateFormat;
}

var stringDate = "March 10, 2017";
var reFormat = dateFormat(stringDate);
console.log(stringDate + " => " + reFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method :

```
function formattedDate(d = new Date) {
  let month = String(d.getMonth() + 1);
  let day = String(d.getDate());
  const year = String(d.getFullYear());

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return `${day},${month}/${year}`;
}
```

Comment: So how would you use your code with this very input: `'March 10, 2017'` that is a string?

Answer (score 0):

Try as below if you prefer "**dd/MM/YYYY**" format

```
function formatDate()
{
   var str = "February 9, 2017";
   var varDate = new Date(str);
   var d = varDate.getDate();
   var m = varDate.getMonth() + 1;
   var y = varDate.getFullYear();
   var dateString = (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + '/' + (m <= 9 ? '0' + m : m) + '/' + y;   
   alert(dateString);
   return false;
}
```

Try this if you prefer "**MM/dd/YYYY**" format :

```
function formatDate()
{
  var str = "February 9, 2017";
  var varDate = new Date(str);
  alert(varDate.toLocaleDateString());   // "MM/dd/YYYY" format
  return false;
}
```